# How do I show all different strings in an ARRAY in DIFFERENT textboxes?

Tags: c#, arrays, string

I have an array and i want every "string" in this array to be a different string. I am a Beginner so I am sorry if this is really easy.

`Values[] --> ("Cat", "Dog", Mouse")`

And I want to get 3 different strings:

```
Value1 --> "Cat"

Value2 --> "Dog"

Value3 --> "Mouse"
```

Thank you :)

Comment: What is this? -> `Values[] --> ("Cat", "Dog", Mouse")` does it array or object?

Comment: it is an array.

Answer (score 3):

For single-dimensional arrays, the foreach statement processes elements in increasing index order, starting with index 0 . [Refer For more information](https://www.dotnetperls.com/foreach)

```
string[] values = {"Cat", "Dog", "Mouse"};
    foreach (string i in values)
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine(i);
    }
```

Comment: Thank you! And how do i show "Cat", "Dog" and "Mouse" in 3 different textboxes? Because I work with Windows Forms Application.

Comment: @StefanKraßnig : You can create array of textbox TextBox[] array = { firstTextBox, secondTextBox }; then assigned from loop

Comment: A ListBox is generally used in this situation rather than text boxes because you currently have 3 items in the array but could have 10 or 20 etc